# Navbar dropdown menu doesnot show the content when the navabar is collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have created a navbar with some links on it and some links have dropdown links. But now when I am reducing the screen size the navbar collapses but the when expanded the dropdown menu is not working.

This my collapse button code.

```
<a class="toggle-nav" href="#"><img src="../img/nav.png" /></a>
```

M Script goes like this

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
            jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

My navbar code is:

```
<div id="logo">
        <a href="/" ><img src="../img/3d.png" class="image-responsive"/></a>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul class="active">
            <li class="spots"><a href="/spots">SPOTS</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">PRODUCTS
        <span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <li class="printers"><a href="../3dprinters">3D PRINTERS</a></li>

            <li class="scanners"><a href="../3dscanners">3D SCANNERS</a></li>

            <li class="consumable"><a href="../filaments.php">FILAMENTS</a></li>

            </ul>

            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SERVICES
        <span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="printing"><a href="../services.php">PRINTING SERVICES</a></li>

            <li class="printing"><a href="#">3D DESIGNING</a></li>
            <
            <li class="printing"><a href="#">3D SCANNING</a></li>

            </ul>

            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">LEARN
        <span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <li class="learn"><a href="../workshop">WORKSHOPS</a></li>

            <li class="learn"><a href="#">GUEST LECTURES</a></li>

            <li class="learn"><a href="#">CORPORATE TRAINING</a></li>

            </ul>

            </li>      

            <li class="learn"><a href="../contacts.php">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>

            <a class="toggle-nav" href="#"><img src="../img/nav.png" /></a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: please add definition of your navigation bar (HTML)

Comment: IN this case the thing that is not important is the collapse button.

Comment: do you have JQuery added to you build - try moving the `e.preventDeafult()` to the top before the `toggleClass()`, Do you get an alert when clicked if you add one.

Comment: My issue is that the navbar is collapsing and on clicking the button it is expanding but the links that have drop downs doesnot open the dropdown menu on clicking it works fine in desktops and laptops. The issue occurs when it is viewed in mobile view

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your problem.

Comment: @Aakash didnt get you

Comment: Sharing a link:https://fiddle.jshell.net/L0xpqfy6/

Comment: This fiddle has your code. Just add any css if you have in CSS section and reproduce the problem over there.

Comment: yeah but it is not working when I viewed in mobile view

Comment: Can you add any CSS if you have in your code Akhilraj?

Comment: I have applied the css. Please check it and help me

Comment: Helloo Anyone there to help